# Node Js Authentication

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication

I'm developing a web application using node.js for home automation using raspberry pi.
As I have to open the web page to the outside, I would like you to advise me what is the best and secure way to do the user authentication to avoid not authorized people to enter the main web page that controls something in the house (ex. Switch on/off the heater).

Comment: A login form? A static user/pass cfg in your app would probs do

Answer (score 1):

If you are using express to render your website with node.js, you can use passportjs to easily add authentication using a variety of strategies.  http://passportjs.org/